# How to resolve this? connection refused GitHub

Tags: tails

git clone https://sherlock-project/sherlock.git

PERROR torsocks[25258]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect () at socks5.c:202)
fatal: unable to acess 'https://sherlock-project/sherlock.git': Could not resolve host: socks5

I'm currently using Tails

when I apply the following commands;

### git config --global http.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'

git config --global https.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'

this error happens;

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/sherlock-project/sherlock.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9050 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

I'm a beginner on the subject

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Socks5**s** not just Socks5. The difference is that in S-case DNS resolving is handed to the proxy. Looks like you have DNS filtered too, so it can not resolve the hostname and start to access *the resolved IP address* through a proxy specified. Also a good practice is to set the resolver to Tor's DNSPort as well